# How to hold the highlighted section for sometime in VIM editor

Tags: vim, vi

I am right now analyzing some code using `VI` editor. In my use case, I have selected code spanning **2 Pages** by using `ESC` `SHIFT` `v` & selecting all the lines (Spanning **2 Pages**). Now the issue I have is I am not able to hold the highlight until I need. As soon as I press ESC and move the cursor the highlight goes off.

How do I hold the highlight until my need

Comment: Pressing escape leaves visual mode.

Comment: It sounds like you may like the [NrrwRgn](https://github.com/chrisbra/NrrwRgn) plugin.  It can open the highlighted text in its own window where you can manipulate it independently of the rest of the data in the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to reselect whatever you previously selected when you leave visual mode you can use `gv`. You can't keep highlight when leaving a `visual mode`, though.

Edit:

If you just need to view selected text and you don't want to be distracted by surrounding text, you can simply copy it to an empty buffer. To do so select your text in visual mode, press `y` then `:new` then `P`. When you finish you can close newly created buffer with `:bd!`.